# SEO tips on changing blog pagination

Tags: seo, url, google-index, blog, pagination

Three years ago we launched a self-made blog area on our e-commerce website. Call it an experimental feature, if you know what I mean.

We had, and still have, a very minimalistic URL schema:

- `/blog/2016/04/27/todays-blog-post/` → a post
- `/blog/` → the archive of *all* posts in the blog, since 2013

Nowadays, we have hundreds of posts, all in one page (the archive), and that's a very slow and non-scalable area of the website: a very bad design choice, isn't it?

Nevertheless, Google indexer seems to really appreciate our blog archive page, its ranking in search results is always very good! So, we don't want to lose even a little of all that goodness!

Anyway, we can't leave that page growing larger, so we did some refactoring to introduce a simple blog-style pagination, using the typical "[older posts / newer posts]" links, pointing to a new URL schema:

- `/blog` → page1
- `/blog/p/2/` → page2
- `/blog/p/3/` → page3

My first question is: how Google will treat (or it's likely to) our change? Will it re-index without losing ranking?

The second one: *is that a good URL schema for such purpose? Is that SEO-friendly enough?* (maybe it would be better to put the page number as a query parameter, instead of using a REST path?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you divide an article into sections, you want to apply pagination HTML in your code to make search engines understand that what you are presenting are sections of a document (much like pages of a book). This URL shows HTML code you can use for pagination:

https://yoast.com/rel-next-prev-paginated-archives/

If you don't use proper pagination, then search engines might index your content improperly. Here's more info on paginated content direct from google's site:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663744?hl=en

It states:

> Use rel="next" and rel="prev" links to indicate the relationship between component URLs. This markup provides a strong hint to Google that you would like us to treat these pages as a logical sequence, thus consolidating their linking properties and usually sending searchers to the first page.

Google should be able to re-index your pages fine, especially if on each page in a paginated series, theres an option to view the next and previous pages.

Your friendly URL setup of `/blog/p/number` is good. I'd go against using parameters such as `/blog/something.php?page=number` just because it might give hackers new ideas since internal parameters names are exposed to the public where as in friendly URLs they don't have to be.

Comment: Great answer. What about canonical? How should we set it in this case?